# Can I use facebook graph api to get locations of all members of my group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get all members of my group using graph api and then delete members from my group which are not in a specified area.

Can I get the location of a group if I am an admin of a group using graph api.

Comment: No, you can get the user location only after the user grants your app permission.

Comment: @CBroe What if everyone has given permission?

Comment: I want to get location of all the members even those which has not granted permissions is there no way to do that?

Comment: Of course there isn’t.

Comment: Only way is to browse their profile or ask them personally and then decide whom to kick

Comment: ok so is there a way we can add restriction to a group in facebook to only get requests from a specific region ?

Comment: no, there is no way. as admin, you can check out the profile of new members though, before accepting them.